# Gridworld-How to gain access to GridPanel from World

Tags: gridworld

I am working on a basic RPG using the Gridworld api for my Comp Sci class, I have movement fully working but I want to keep the grid centered around the main character which should be done from the recenter method in GridPanel, currently I am using my own world object and as that is the only thing declared in the main method I should be capable of getting the DisplayPanel object from there but I cannot find a way to do so. Does anybody know how I can get an instance of the current DisplayPanel object?

Answer (score 0):

To call the recenter() method using your `ActorWorld` do this:

```
ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
...
world.show();

WorldFrame frame = (WorldFrame) world.frame;
frame.display.recenter(/*Your Location*/);
```

Sadly `frame` is private so you  need to go into `WorldFrame` and declare it as public. If you are still using the `gridworld.jar` as an external resource you are going to need to import all its packages into your own project. I explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481990/changing-the-gridpanel-class-in-gridworld/23501854#23501854).

In case you didn't know `recenter()` actually centers the upper left corner on the `Location` not the actual center of the `Grid`. To do that you will need to edit the `recenter()` method in `GridPanel` (line 358).

Hope this helps, let me know if you need help importing the packages from `gridworld.jar`.

Comment: I came to the solution of partitioning the world into multiple grids which can be moved between seamlessly, which allows me to more easily implement random world generation. Also for accessing private fields I simply have been using reflection up until this point to avoid editing the base files.